# Encapsulating ListBox in public property

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, properties, mvp

In a `MVP` applicaiton if I want to encapsulate a `ListBox` in a public property so that I could expose the property through an interface to the presenter. I should be able to update the items in the `ListBox` though this public property. I've tried in several ways to do this

```
    public BindingSource  Permission
    {
        get { return lstGivenPermissions.DataSource; } // Casting error
        set { lstGivenPermissions.DataSource = value; }
    }
```

I tried several types for the property like `IEnumereble<>`, `List<>` etc. but always either setter or geter shows a casting error.

One option is to have separate properties for `get` and `set`.

```
   public ListBox gettingPermission
   {
        get {return lstGivenPermissions; }
   }

    public BindingSource  Permission
    {
        set { lstGivenPermissions.DataSource = value; }
    }
```

Is it possible to use a single property in this case or else having two properties is a acceptable solution?

**EDIT :** I'm using MVP pattern and my requirement is that my presenters are talking to the Views through interfaces. So that if I want one of my presenters to access controllers (like text boxes) in the View, those controllers should be encapsulated in properties. So that I can expose through the interface.

Comment: Why do you want the `ListBox` to be mutable through a public property? You're breaking encapsulation if you do that.

Comment: Actually what I want to do is that my presentation classes need to access / update the content (items) in list boxes those are in the View.

Comment: The presentation classes talk to the view through a interface. So that only properties in the View could be exposed!

Comment: You can just look at the type of `DataSource` to see what type it is, and to see that it is not in fact `BindingSource`, `IEnumerable`, or `List`.

Comment: I know that. what am I asking ,is how to solve this?

Comment: This solved my problem> get { return lstGivenPermissions.Items.Cast<string>().ToList(); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem.

```
    public List<string>  GivenPermission
    {
        get { return lstGivenPermissions.Items.Cast<string>().ToList(); }
        set { lstGivenPermissions.DataSource = value; }
    }
```